# Listing Sub-Directories in Drop Down box

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, directory, subdirectory

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this code? It is supposed to display all folders in `../files/`, however, it is returning an empty list. This is the code:

```
<?php
    $upload_dir  = chdir("./files/" . $userid);
    $dirs = glob($upload_dir, GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    foreach($dirs as $val){
       echo '<option value="'.$val.'">'.$val."</option>\n";
    }       
?>
```

Comment: You say "It is supposed to display all folders in `../files/`" but your code says `chdir("./files/" . $userid)` ... which one do you want? They're totally different things.

Comment: Recall your directory path. Try to use absolute system path to your directory. Check directory permissions

Comment: @itchy it displays foders in /files/$userid sry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got `$upload_dir` set to the return from `chdir`, which will be a TRUE or a FALSE, and then try to use that as your argument to glob when settings $dirs.

The first argument to [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) should be a string, representing a pattern.  In your case, you'll probably want * to list all contents (instead of the TRUE or FALSE you're passing in).  Think of the first argument to glob as what you would pas to `dir` on Windows, or to `ls` in Linux, so in this case `/files/userid/*` or something similar.

I'd do something like this instead:

```
<?php
    $pattern = "./files/" . $userid . '/*';
    $dirs = glob($pattern, GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    foreach($dirs as $val){
       echo '<option value="'.$val.'">'.$val."</option>\n";
    }       
?>
```

This has the advantage of not changing the current working directory.  Ideally, I'd use an absolute path instead of the relative path there.

Comment: Hi, that worked. Thanks! Also, is there a method to remove the './files/' from the drop down ?

Comment: Sure, lots of ways to do so.  First thoughts that come to mind would be either [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php), [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), or [explode](http://us2.php.net/explode)

Answer (score 2):

`chdir()` returns `true` or `false` depending on whether changing the directory worked. So you basically try to find all files named either `1` or `0`. If there is any clearly defined behaviour of this at all.

Try it like this:

```
<?php
    if (chdir("./files/" . $userid)) {
       $dirs = glob('*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
       foreach($dirs as $val){
          echo '<option value="'.$val.'">'.$val."</option>\n";
       }        
    } else {
       echo 'Changing directory failed.';
    }
?>
```

Comment: I think that should be `glob('*', GLOB_ONLYDIR)`

Comment: @ernie glob('*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) only returns an empty drop down menu

Comment: @Brian I you want to use this solution, you need to use all the code, not just the one line.  The `chdir` is critical so that `glob` will run in the right location.